# Collecting two sensors simultaneously android wear

Tags: wear-os, android-sensors

Is it possible to send multiple sensors data (accelerometer + gyro +magnetomer) simultaneously using android wear? I understand that we can send multiple sensors data but not at the exact same timestamp. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by "sending"?

Comment: I mean sending data from a wearable device to a phone

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you have a collection of data points (sensor data in this case) and you want to sync them across all connected devices in one shot, then can't you simply use a DataMap to put all the data points in there and then use PutDataMapRequest to sync that data as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html#SyncData)? If you don't want to sync across all the nodes on your network and only want to target a subset of devices (phone seems to be your target in this case), then you can actually use [MessageApi](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) to do that; you define a capability for the target node and then on any other node, you first search for the node(s) that have the desired capability and then you send a message to them. The payload for a message is a byte array so you can have all the data points that you want put together in a su=ingle byte array (for example, create a simple json like string from your data points and convert the string to a byte array).